# Multiple Route between two location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I am drawing a single route between two location by this [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/). but I want to draw multiple route between two location. I am new for Google Map development. so please help me to find out multiple route

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get multiple routes you have to add alternatives parameter as this on your url:

> alternatives=true

Comment: Thanks pablobu, but its show only single alternate route, not all possible route or more than two or three routes simultaneously.

Comment: Shashank there is no way to specify how many alternatives routes the service is going to return, 
From documentation of directions api: "alternatives — If set to true, specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server."